# how to customize simple_list_item_multiplechoice.xml file

Tags: android

here i used this code to display contacts with check boxes....

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.**simple_list_item_multiple_choice,c**,
                        new String[] {
                            //Phone.TYPE,
                            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            Phone.NUMBER
                        },
                        new int[] { android.R.id.**text1**, android.R.id.**text2** });
```

its working well ..but not showing contact number..showing only name with checkboxes each row.to do this ,i created my ownlayout and placed main instead of simple_list_itemmultiplechoice as below

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.**main**,c,
                        new String[] {
                            //Phone.TYPE,
                            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            Phone.NUMBER
                        },
                        new int[] { android.R.id.**text_name**, android.R.id.**text_phone** });
```

but its showing error as **main cannot be resolved or is not a field**

can u solve my problem..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `R.layout.main` without `android` prefix. Use all ids from this layout without prefix too.